# Can I train a model for gender prediction using images in which I have 2 faces?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a model for **gender prediction** and my dataset contains images in which there are several faces in the same image.

I have labels for them with face scores but I have the gender label just for the face with the biggest score.

I trained my model with only images with 1 face but the database has shrunk considerably.

I want to have more data in the dataset, but I don't know if the accuracy will change if I add the images with 2 faces.

Can I adapt the network in some way? Any advice?

```
img_dim = 128
inputs = Input(shape = (img_dim, img_dim, 3))

# Begin
model_t = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', strides = 2, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (img_dim, img_dim, 3))(inputs)
model_t = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (3, 3), strides= 2)(model_t)
model_t = BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.15)(model_t)

model_t = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(model_t)
model_t = BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.15)(model_t)

model_t = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(model_t)
model_t = Flatten()(model_t)

gender_model = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(model_t)
gender_model = Dropout(0.4)(gender_model)
gender_model = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid',name = 'gender')(gender_model)

model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = gender_model)
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.002), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: First, is there a possibility to crop these images with several faces in multiple images from your dataset? (This would help with the amount of data). Second, when training your model with only images of 1 face, you could consider implementing Data Augmentation.

Comment: I have developed a function that detects the faces in an image and has an option to return  either all the faces or just the largest face. I used that to preprocess my images so the resultant image for the data set has only one facial image. You can download the dataset from kaggle at https://www.kaggle.com/gpiosenka/gender-classification-from-an-image.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! I am new to this and still learning!